# how to check if dispatch_async has finished executing the block

Tags: multithreading, dispatch-async

I have a question on dispatch_async. i want to make sure that the queue finish executing because i need to return a value that is only obtained when the block is done.

```
    dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("flickr downloader", NO); 

    dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
        NSArray *photos = [[FlickrFetcher photosInPlace:self.listOfPlacesChosenPlaceDictionary maxResults:50] mutableCopy];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.photoAtThePlace = photos; 
        });
    });

     dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
     return  [self.photoAtThePlace mutableCopy];
```

currently the return value will be nil because the dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{..} is yet to be executed when the return function is called. How do i make sure that this get done before return is called? Thanks!

Comment: ok problem sovled. The problem is must put the block into a dispatch group and use dispatch_group_wait.. but apparently it doesnt work well with main thread. so i will have to use 2 different thread that i created. i assume that main thread is too buzy so we do not really get in time to call main thread before we return.
    
Maybe someone can enlighten me on the main thread problem. because if i put dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{...}); then the code wont work. THankx!

Comment: Hi, TanC, please put your comment into the answer section and elaborate why it doesn't work well with main thread if you have time. I come across similar problem and I really want to know the correct way of resolving this. Thank you in advance.